# Changing a geolocation map within HTML5 with selection made from drop down box

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am coding a project for school. I have already included code for geolocation upon the page loading. It is required to have a drop down box to bring up three additional locations. I have also included the coded drop down box. I am thinking that to change the map_canvas id I need to include if statements with the included google maps that I have for Walt Disney World, Honolulu, and Paris. I am not sure exactly how to code this if statement as to change the map image shown based on the selection. Here is what I have:

**CSS**

```
html{ 
    height: 90% 
}
body{ 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}
#map_canvas{ 
    height: 90%; 
    width: 90%; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var watchID;
var geo; // for the geolocation object
var map; // for the google map object
var mapMarker; // the google map marker object

// position options
var MAXIMUM_AGE = 200; // miliseconds
var TIMEOUT = 300000;
var HIGHACCURACY = true;

function getGeoLocation() {
  try {
    if (!!navigator.geolocation) return navigator.geolocation;
    else return undefined;
  } catch (e) {
    return undefined;
  }
}

function show_map(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

  if (map) {
    map.panTo(latlng);
    mapMarker.setPosition(latlng);
  } else {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: latlng,

      // mapTypeID --
      // ROADMAP displays the default road map view
      // SATELLITE displays Google Earth satellite images
      // HYBRID displays a mixture of normal and satellite views
      // TERRAIN displays a physical map based on terrain information.
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.setTilt(0); // turns off the annoying default 45-deg view

    mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      title: "You are here."
    });
    mapMarker.setMap(map);
  }
}

function geo_error(error) {
  stopWatching();
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert('Geolocation Timeout');
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert('Geolocation Position unavailable');
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert('Geolocation Permission denied');
      break;
    default:
      alert('Geolocation returned an unknown error code: ' + error.code);
  }
}

function stopWatching() {
  if (watchID) geo.clearWatch(watchID);
  watchID = null;
}

function startWatching() {
  watchID = geo.watchPosition(show_map, geo_error, {
    enableHighAccuracy: HIGHACCURACY,
    maximumAge: MAXIMUM_AGE,
    timeout: TIMEOUT
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  if ((geo = getGeoLocation())) {
    startWatching();
  } else {
    alert('Geolocation not supported.')
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<section>
  <div id="vacationLocations">
    <h2>Vacation Locations</h2>
    <form name="tripSelection" method="post" method="get">
      <div class="formRow">
        <label for="serviceSelection">
          Trip Selection</label>
        <select name="tripSelection" id="tripSelection" class="validated" required>
          <option value="">-Select One-</option>
          <option value="1">Paris, France</option>
          <option value="2">Honolulu, Hawaii</option>
          <option value="3">Walt Disney World, Florida</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is what I have already in the program and it is working. 
here is the code I have for Disney followed by the coordinates I have found for the other locations:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script
     src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
  </script>

  <script>
  function initialize() {
      var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(28.3341439,-81.5871676),
zoom:14,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
```

Paris, France is  48.8589507,2.2775174

Honolulu, Hawaii is  21.3282956,-157.9390673

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The suggested edit does nothing to assist the code. How would I go about changing the map_canvas to show the selection from the drop down box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to code a working program that does exactly what I was trying to do. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class lang="en">

<!-- 
  geoLocMap.html by Bill Weinman 
  <http://bw.org/contact/>
  created 2011-07-07
  updated 2011-07-20

  Copyright (c) 2011 The BearHeart Group, LLC
  This file may be used for personal educational purposes as needed. 
  Use for other purposes is granted provided that this notice is
  retained and any changes made are clearly indicated as such. 
-->

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 90% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
    #map_canvas { height: 90%; width: 90% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var watchID;
    var geo;    // for the geolocation object
    var map;    // for the google map object
    var mapMarker;  // the google map marker object

    // position options
    var MAXIMUM_AGE = 200; // miliseconds
    var TIMEOUT = 300000;
    var HIGHACCURACY = true;

    function getGeoLocation() {
        try {
            if( !! navigator.geolocation ) return navigator.geolocation;
            else return undefined;
        } catch(e) {
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    function show_map(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        if(map) {
            map.panTo(latlng);
            mapMarker.setPosition(latlng);
        } else {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: latlng,

                // mapTypeID --
                // ROADMAP displays the default road map view
                // SATELLITE displays Google Earth satellite images
                // HYBRID displays a mixture of normal and satellite views
                // TERRAIN displays a physical map based on terrain information.
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            map.setTilt(0); // turns off the annoying default 45-deg view

            mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                title:"You are here."
            });
            mapMarker.setMap(map);
        }
    }

    function geo_error(error) {
        stopWatching();
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert('Geolocation Timeout');
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert('Geolocation Position unavailable');
                break;
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert('Geolocation Permission denied');
                break;
            default:
                alert('Geolocation returned an unknown error code: ' + error.code);
        }
    }

    function stopWatching() {
        if(watchID) geo.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }

    function startWatching() {
        watchID = geo.watchPosition(show_map, geo_error, {
            enableHighAccuracy: HIGHACCURACY,
            maximumAge: MAXIMUM_AGE,
            timeout: TIMEOUT
        });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        if((geo = getGeoLocation())) {
            startWatching();
        } else {
            alert('Geolocation not supported.')
        }
    }
</script>
<!--Changes added by Eric Wood  -->
<script>
    function tripChange() {
        var s = document.getElementById("tripSelection");
        var tripSelection = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

        if (tripSelection == 1) {
            value1();
        }else if(tripSelection == 2){
            value2();
        }else if(tripSelection == 3){
            value3();
        }
    }
            function value1() {
                var mapProp = {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(48.8589507,2.2775174),
                    zoom:14,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var Map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapProp);
            }

            function value2() {
                var mapProp = {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(21.3282956,-157.9390673),
                    zoom:14,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var Map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapProp);
            }

            function value3() {
                var mapProp = {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(28.3341439,-81.5871676),
                    zoom:14,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var Map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapProp);
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <section>
    <div id="vacationLocations" >
        <h2>Vacation Locations</h2>
    <form name="tripSelection" method="post" method="get" >
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="serviceSelection">
             Trip Selection</label>
            <select name="tripSelection" id="tripSelection" class="validated" onchange="tripChange()" required>
                <option value="">-Select One-</option>
                <option value="1">Paris, France</option>
                <option value="2">Honolulu, Hawaii</option>
                <option value="3">Walt Disney World, Florida</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```